# Exchange 2003 to 2010 migration: Can I remove free/busy public folder once all users are moved?

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders, scheduling, availability

Now that all my mailboxes are on the 2010 server, can I remove the schedule+free/busy public folder? I am having scheduling synchronization issues, and I believe it may be at fault. All clients are using Outlook 2010 or 2007. Can I just get rid of the schedule+free/busy public folder entirely?

Comment: I don't think so. I would start here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397225(EXCHG.80).aspx